# How to change Angular UI Datepicker model value format in angular formly?

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly, angular-ui-datepicker

Here is the default format of UI Datepicker of angular formly

```
  {
    "date": "2015-10-05T18:30:00.000Z"
  }
```

How to change the above format into

```
  {
    "date": "2015/10/05"
  }
```

Here is the JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/cadaga/2/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, in the model you store the date in ISO format like you already have, and you format it in the view as you wish, using the `date` filter ([documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/docs/api/ng/filter/date)):

```
<div>{{vm.model.date | date: 'yyyy/MM/dd'}}</div>
```

If you anyway want to change the format in the model, inject `$filter` and use `date` filter like the following:

> `$filter('date')(date_value, format, timezone)`

e.g:

```
$filter('date')(vm.model.date, 'yyyy/MM/dd');
```

Alternatively, if you are manipulating dates a lot, a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) can be useful.

---

Edit: Noticed you want to change the date model value in the concrete context of angular-formly with a datepicker component.
The component needs the date model value to be in a ***standard format***, but what you can do is to have another property with the corresponding formatted date, that you would set *on change* of the date input:

**HTML (on the datepicker `input`):**

```
ng-change="vm.setFormattedDate(dt)"
```

**Controller:**

```
vm.setFormattedDate = function (datetime) {
    vm.model.formattedDate = $filter('date')(datetime, 'yyyy/MM/dd');
}
```